# Java class from jython

Tags: java, jython

I need to access the java class which is running jython script from that script?
Any help?

update:
Something like this:

```
//JAVA CLASS
class Test{
     public String text;
     public Test
     {
        PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter(null);
        pi.execfile("test.py");

     }

}
```

So int test.py I need to do something to change the value of text in Test class

```
#test.py
doSomething()
Text.test = "new value"
```

Hope it is more clear

Comment: Can you clarify ? Do you mean a class that has spawned a Jython script ?

Comment: in order to clarify your question please add post some code

Comment: @Brian Agnew He wants to pass a Java instance to the script that he executes. That is possible with embeded jython.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass a java class instance to the [embeded jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/userguide.html#embedding-jython) you need to do:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    interp.set("a", this);
    interp.exec("a.test = 'new value'");
```

If you want to call a function (that takes the instance as an argument) from a external script:

```
 PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    interp.set("a", this);
    interp.exec("import externalscript");
    interp.exec("externalscript.function(a)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your test class at the top of your Jython code. I believe this would be something along the lines of

```
from com.examplepackage import Test
```

You'll also to set your text value as static, or pass the Java object into the Jython method.

Check out the article [here](http://www.jython.org/docs/usejava.html).